# Checkboxes doesn`t get value of a textarea

Tags: javascript, function, module

I need to create 4 checkboxes, which will get textarea value and execute some functions from the module. However, checkboxes dont get the value, and that is my problem. Ive tried to put text.addEventListener to each function and to checkbox eventListeners as well, but it doesn`t work.

Hope, you could give me some kind of solution.
Thanks in advance!

```
let text = document.querySelector('#text');

;(function() {

    let a = (text.value.split(' ').filter(elem => elem != ''));
    let b = a.join('').split('');

    function wordsNumber() {
        console.log(a);
        console.log('The number of words is ' + a.length + '!');
    }

    function symbolsNumber() {
        length = 0;
        for (let elem of a) {
            length += elem.length;
        }
        console.log('The number of symbols without backspace is ' + length + '!');
    }

    function symbolsNumberWithBackspace() {
        console.log('The number of symbols with backspace is ' + text.value.length + '!');
    }

    function counter() {
        let count = {};
        for (let elem of b) {
            if (count[elem] === undefined) {
                count[elem] = 1;
            }
            else {
                count[elem]++;
            }
        }
        for (let elem in count) {
            count[elem]=(Number(count[elem]/b.length)*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        }
        console.log(count);
    }
    window.func = {wordsNumber, symbolsNumber, symbolsNumberWithBackspace, counter}
})();

let checkbox1 = document.querySelector('#check1');
let checkbox2 = document.querySelector('#check2');
let checkbox3 = document.querySelector('#check3');
let checkbox4 = document.querySelector('#check4');

checkbox1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox1.checked) {
        func.wordsNumber();
    }
})

checkbox2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox2.checked) {
        func.symbolsNumber();
    }
})

checkbox3.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox3.checked) {
        func.symbolsNumberWithBackspace();
    }
})

checkbox4.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox4.checked) {
        func.counter();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to update variables `a` and `b` on text input, like this:

```js
let text = document.querySelector('#text');

;(function() {

    let a, b;
    text.addEventListener('input', function () {
      a = (text.value.split(' ').filter(elem => elem != ''));
      b = a.join('').split('');
    });

    function wordsNumber() {
        console.log(a);
        console.log('The number of words is ' + a.length + '!');
    }

    function symbolsNumber() {
        length = 0;
        for (let elem of a) {
            length += elem.length;
        }
        console.log('The number of symbols without backspace is ' + length + '!');
    }

    function symbolsNumberWithBackspace() {
        console.log('The number of symbols with backspace is ' + text.value.length + '!');
    }

    function counter() {
        let count = {};
        for (let elem of b) {
            if (count[elem] === undefined) {
                count[elem] = 1;
            }
            else {
                count[elem]++;
            }
        }
        for (let elem in count) {
            count[elem]=(Number(count[elem]/b.length)*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        }
        console.log(count);
    }
    window.func = {wordsNumber, symbolsNumber, symbolsNumberWithBackspace, counter}
})();

let checkbox1 = document.querySelector('#check1');
let checkbox2 = document.querySelector('#check2');
let checkbox3 = document.querySelector('#check3');
let checkbox4 = document.querySelector('#check4');

checkbox1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox1.checked) {
        func.wordsNumber();
    }
})

checkbox2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox2.checked) {
        func.symbolsNumber();
    }
})

checkbox3.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox3.checked) {
        func.symbolsNumberWithBackspace();
    }
})

checkbox4.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checkbox4.checked) {
        func.counter();
    }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
<input type="checkbox" id="check2">
<input type="checkbox" id="check3">
<input type="checkbox" id="check4">
```